# Разделение строк в excel через pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Всем привет.
Есть вопрос, можно ли разделить значения вот в такой таблице excel построчно?
То есть нужно сделать так, чтобы каждая строка содержала одно конкретное значение в каждом столбце, а именно из такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделать такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, можно. Что именно не получается?

Comment: Не получается правильно перебрать значения строк.
Файл большой и во многих строках > 10 значений, притом разделители могут быть как ; так и \n
Судя по всему нужно идти через split,
df['gr1'] = df['gr1'].str.split('\n')
    print(df['gr1'][0][0])
но опыта пока с DataFrame не много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменяем `\n` на `;` для единообразия, затем режем сплитом по `;`, далее по очереди "взрываем" полученные списки, размножая строки. Затем удаляем дубликаты.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'num': {0: '1.0.1', 1: '1.0.2'}, 'grl': {0: 'vpn\nWiFi_SSID', 1: 'vpn\nWiFi_SSID'}, 'seg': {0: None, 1: None},
     'gr2': {0: 'ip_l', 1: 'ip_2'}, 'protocol': {0: 'HTTPS', 1: 'XMPP;XMPP;XMPP;XMPP\nHTTPS'},
     'port': {0: '443', 1: '5235\n5228\n5229\n5230\n443'}, 'status': {0: 'Изменено', 1: 'Изменено'}})
print('\nИсходный\n',df)
cols = ['grl', 'protocol', 'port']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\n', ';').str.split(';'))
df = df.explode('grl').explode('protocol').explode('port').drop_duplicates(cols)
print('\nИтог\n',df)
```

```
Исходный
      num             grl   seg   gr2                    protocol                         port    status
0  1.0.1  vpn\nWiFi_SSID  None  ip_l                       HTTPS                          443  Изменено
1  1.0.2  vpn\nWiFi_SSID  None  ip_2  XMPP;XMPP;XMPP;XMPP\nHTTPS  5235\n5228\n5229\n5230\n443  Изменено

Итог
      num        grl   seg   gr2 protocol  port    status
0  1.0.1        vpn  None  ip_l    HTTPS   443  Изменено
0  1.0.1  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_l    HTTPS   443  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2     XMPP  5235  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2     XMPP  5228  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2     XMPP  5229  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2     XMPP  5230  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2     XMPP   443  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5235  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5228  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5229  Изменено
1  1.0.2        vpn  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5230  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2     XMPP  5235  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2     XMPP  5228  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2     XMPP  5229  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2     XMPP  5230  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2     XMPP   443  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5235  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5228  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5229  Изменено
1  1.0.2  WiFi_SSID  None  ip_2    HTTPS  5230  Изменено
```

Comment: `.astype(str)` вроде и не нужно, и так работает, хотя может просто пример такой

Comment: На всякий случай, если порт будет целым числом, во избежание исключения

Comment: Да, вы правы, если вся серия будет не типа `object`, то `.str` аксессор использовать не удастся, я проверил. Ну ладно )